# How to ask user to input and that's should be required

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From a shell script, I want to ask the user to input data such as database name, database user etc.

When the user inadvertently presses the enter key, the input is blank. How do I make the input required? If the input is blank, the script asks that question again?

My current script, but maybe it doesn't work as I expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Clear terminal first
clear

echo -n "Your Database Name : "
read dbname
if [ "$dbname" = "" ]; then
   echo "ANSWER CANNOT BE BLANK!"
   echo -n "Your Database Name : "
   read dbname
else
... another code here
```

But this does not rule out the possibility that the user does not accidentally (or even perhaps on purpose) hit the enter key – how many if else condition do I have to make?

Answer (score 4):

You may use an infinite loop and `break` if input is not empty:

```
while true; do
  echo -n "Your Database Name: "
  read dbname
  if [[ "$dbname"  != "" ]]
  then
    echo "dbname = $dbname"
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Or even better: `dbname=; until [[ $dbname ]]; do read -rp "Your Database Name: " dbname; done; echo "dbname=$dbname"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash -

clear

echo -n "Your Database Name: "

while read dbname; do
  test "$dbname" != "" && break
  echo "ANSWER CANNOT BE BLANK!"
  echo -n "Your Database Name : "
done

echo "dbname = $dbname"
```

**Edit: fix for Ctrl-D**

The above-mentioned code leaves an empty string, if the user enters `Ctrl-D`. The following version handles this case:

```
#!/bin/bash -

clear

until read -r -p "Your Database Name: " db && test "$db" != ""; do
  continue
done

echo "db='$db'"
```

Note, we use the Bash builtin `read` command. If the user enters `Ctrl-D`(manual *end-of-file*), the `read` command exits with non-zero status, which is interpreted as error.  See `info bash 'read'`.

This version will also work in non-interactive mode:

```
echo -e "\n name \n" | ./script.sh
```

Comment: Broken: if user presses Ctrl-D, you'll have an empty variable `dbname`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, yes. It is also broken if user presses Ctrl-K, then Enter. That's just a simple answer to a simple question. By the way, the answer with `while true` doesn't work in non-interactive mode. So what? The OP will adjust the loop according to his needs.

Comment: With Ctrl-K, `dbname` isn't empty: it's a valid filename, `$'\v'`. What do you mean by _the answer with `while true` doesn't work in non-interactive mode?_

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, `echo '' | ./script`. Well, it actually works. But I guess not the way he probably wants it.

Comment: Oh, that! well, in fact it _does_ work! no commands will be launched with random (empty) arguments.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, yes, just as the user is unlikely to enter Ctrl-D.

Comment: That's the kind of assumptions that yield bad software. Sorry, I don't buy it. And the “problem” with the other answer is easily fixed by adding, e.g., `|| exit 1` after the `read` statement.

Comment: any solutions to do that? , after all, for what the user presses CTRL + D when running this script wkwkwkw, so I feel maybe this solution can be tried, :D

Comment: @RizalFakhri, I've added another version to the answer.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I seem a bit strange at the code, but i'll try it :D BTW thanks :)